# RXJava, How to execute two observeables asynchronously, run a function once both have completed, and get the time difference between both threads?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

Im looking for an elegant way to run two observable's at the same time, wait for both to finish (They both fetch data from the web) and only once both have completed perform a function.

I also need to get a time difference between the two threads? Is there an elegant way to do this in RXJava, specifically for android. Or will i have to set a global timer variable in the oncomplete methods of both observable's and only compare them after?

My thinking is to merge the observeables into one, but then im not sure how to get the time difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the timestamped sequence of the two sources:

```
Observable<A> sourceA = ...
Observable<B> sourceB = ...

Observable.zip(sourceA.timestamp(), sourceB.timestamp(), (a, b) -> {
     long timediff = a.time() - b.time();
     A itemA = a.value();
     B itemB = b.value();
     return itemA + ", " + itemB;
})
.subscribe(...);
```